# How do you fix rounding error in snowflake when doing calculation?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm getting rounding error in snowflake when trying to perform the following calculation.

```
select ROUND(84186926/91.0)*91.0
```

The answer I'm getting is 84186921. However, the correct answer is 84186926.

Is there a way to fix this rounding error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your expected answer is wrong.  You are dividing, then rounding, then multiplying by the same divisor.  The fractional part of the division is 0.0549.  Multiply that by 91, and you get 5, which is the difference between 84,186,926 and 84,186,921.

Comment: Why do you think that 84186926 is the correct answer?  That looks clearly wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly welcome to floating point numbers.
If you `84186926 / 91.0` in Windows Calculator you get `925131.0549450549`
which if you `* 91` gives you the answer you expect.

Snowflake on the over hand defaults to 6 decimal places so `84186926 / 91.0` gives you `925131.054945`
You are then using the `ROUND()` function which defaults to zero decimal places, so you are getting `925131`
Then you multiply by `91.0`, giving `84186921`

So even if you were to move the closing brackets to be `ROUND(4186926/91.0*91.0)` you would get `4186926`, because now you are ROUNDING `84186925.9..` but really you should never do divisions first as you lose precision, `4186926*91.0/91.0` gives `4186926.000000` as lose of precision (division) is done last.

The other option is to use a format that has the fixed precision you need like `number(30,15)` thus `84186926::number(30,15)/91.0::number(30,15)` thus giving `925131.054945054945055` but really you should swap the order of the operations.